# How to keep modified object within list after filter is made on adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, filter

I will try to be as explicit as I can. What I am trying to do is implement a filter on my adapter, modify some object attribute and then clean the filter. at this point, if I filter once again the object would have the change I made. The problem I have is that when I filter, I apply a clear to the list.

This is my adapter

```
private fun buildProductAdapter(filter: String) {
    productList = Product().getProductsByFilter(filter)
    productListAdapter = ProductListAdapter(applicationContext, productList, cashOrCredit)
    rcvProducts.adapter = productListAdapter
}
```

this is when I do some filter

```
private fun notifyProductListFilterChanged() {
    val filter: String = if (edtSearchProduct.text.toString() != "") edtSearchProduct.text.toString() else ""
    productList.clear()
    productList.addAll(Product().getProductsByFilter(filter))
    productListAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

I was thinking to use a second list and then update de original list, do the filter over the first, duplicate over the second and this would be the one shown in the adapter.

Any help or suggestions would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
private fun notifyProductListFilterChanged() {
    val filter: String = if (edtSearchProduct.text.toString() != "") edtSearchProduct.text.toString() else ""
    productList.clear()
    productList.addAll(filteredProductList(filter))
    productListAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

}

private fun filteredProductList(filter: String): Collection<Product> {

    return productListBaseAdapter.filter { it.nameProduct.contains(filter) || it.category.contains(filter) || it.descriptionProduct.contains(filter) }

}
```